# Fullcalendar 4, when using eventRender i get error Failure parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using FullCalendar 4 and i have setup the Calendar Object in my script

```
function createBookingCalendar() {

var calendarEl = document.getElementById('bookingCalendar');

let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    locale: 'en-gb', // the initial locale
    timeZone: 'Europe/London',
    plugins: ['interaction', 'list', 'timeGrid'],
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'listDay,listWeek,timeGridDay,timeGridWeek, dayGridWeek,DayGridMonth'
    },
    businessHours: [ // specify an array instead
        {
            daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // Monday - Friday
            startTime: '09:00', // 9am
            endTime: '18:00' // 6pm
        }, {
            daysOfWeek: [6], // Saturday
            startTime: '10:00', // 10am
            endTime: '16:00' // 4pm
        }
    ],
    hiddenDays: [7],
    // customize the button names,
    // otherwise they'd all just say "list"
    views: {
        listDay: {
            buttonText: 'Goto Day View'
        },
        listWeek: {
            buttonText: 'Goto Week View'
        },
        timeGridDay: {
            buttonText: 'Goto Time Grid Day View'
        },
        timeGridWeek: {
            buttonText: 'Goto Time Grid Week View'
        }
    },
    slotDuration: '02:00', // 2 hours
    defaultView: 'listWeek',
    defaultDate: Date.now(),
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    eventSources: [
        // CAD Solutions Event Source (Remote Database)
        {

            url: '../php/getBookings.php',
            method: 'GET',
            failure: function () {

                $.confirm({
                    theme: 'Modern',
                    icon: 'fas fa-exclamation-triangle',
                    title: 'Error',
                    content: '<p>There was an error fetching the bookings from our database, we appologise for the inconvenience.</p><p class="text-muted">This error has been logged with our engineers.</p><small>Error 0x86451 (Fetch Bookings Database Error)</small>',
                    type: 'red',
                    columnClass: 'col-md-6 col-md-offset-3',
                    buttons: {
                        close: {
                            text: 'Close.',
                            action: function () {
                                //reset flag and recall the function.

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    ],
    eventRender: function (info) {

        var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
                    title: info.event.title,
                    content: 'asdadasdqweqweqweqweqwasssd',
                    placement: 'top',
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    container: 'body'
                });


    },
    noEventsMessage: '<div class="panel panel-primary" style="height: 245px;width: 654px;margin:0 auto;padding:10px;margin-top:30px;"><div class="panel-heading"><h4><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> There are no bookings for this day.</h4></div><div class="panel-body"><p>There are no bookings saved for this date, you can add a booking to this day using the buttons below, or select a different date.</p><p class="text-muted">You can create a booking for this date as all timeslots are available.</small></div><div class="panel-footer"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0);" id="addBooking" style="color:#fff;"><i class="fas fa-calendar-plus"></i> Create Booking For This Date.</a></div></div><div class="divider">&nbsp;</div><div class="divider">&nbsp;</div><div class="divider">&nbsp;</div>',

    eventClick: function (info) {
        //Prevent Default Behaviour.
        info.jsEvent.preventDefault();
        $.confirm({
            theme: 'Modern',
            icon: 'fas fa-info-circle',
            title: 'Selected Booking Information',
            content: '<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="assetContent"><li class="list-group-item">Booking Company Name: ' + info.event.extendedProps.companyName + '</li><li class="list-group-item">Booking Date: ' + info.event.start + '</li><li class="list-group-item">Booking Slot: ' + info.event.startTime + ' - ' + info.event.endTime + '</li></ul>',
            type: 'blue',
            columnClass: 'col-md-6 col-md-offset-3',
            buttons: {
                close: {
                    text: 'Close.',
                    action: function () {
                        //reset flag and recall the function.

                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
});

calendar.render();
```

}

When i have **eventRender** setup in the code the calendar stops fetching events from my source and it shows the **eventSources>failure** dialog that i added in the function.

When i remove the eventRender part of the script the calendar object renders perfectly and I am able to see all the events from my database.

Could anybody point out where I am going wrong with the coding?
would really like to get the eventRender part working so i can change the background color of events that are set, also in addition, how would i add in events of my own after the source has fetched the events from the server? I want to do this so I can fill in time slots that are missing in the calendar so the user can select a free slot to create a booking.

Many Thanks

**Edit** I took out the tool tip code I found in the full calendar docs and replaced it with ui tool tip instead, that is now working. What is the procedure for adding in my own events?

Comment: _"so I can fill in time slots that are missing in the calendar so the user can select a free slot to create a booking."_ ...this is really the opposite of how the calendar is intended to be used.  Events should be used to show time which is **not** available, i.e. where a booking has already been made.

Comment: If you want to show available times, then there are some possible options: 1) use [businessHours](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/business-hours) to show regular times when appointments are available, and mark other times outside those hours automatically as unavailable. If that's not flexible enough then I would recommend 2) Using [background events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events) to mark available areas - that way you can allow the user to still select times on top of that.

Comment: And if you're using the timeGrid view, then if you use the [select](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback) callback (instead of dateClick or eventClick or anything else), then a) the user can drag-and-drop to select the start and end dates they require, and b) the calendar will tell you the start and end dates they selected.

Comment: P.S. for the background events idea, if the server knows which times are free, you could provide a [separate feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source-object) of event data from the server to populate these.

Comment: hey! thanks for the reply, I totally get what you are saying, the reason I need to populate the free slots is so that the company can see what slots are not booked and select one of those. The timeslots are in 2 hour blocks - 09:00 - 11:00, 11:00 - 14:00, 14:00 - 16:00 and 16:00 - 18:00. The other issue is that the client wants the slots to be 2 hours in length but needs to allow at least 2 hours for travelling between sites. That is going to make it even more tricky

Comment: I have just had a look at the background events that you linked to on the FullCalendar docs and that looks perfect for what I want to achieve. I think by using backgroundEvents along side the businessHours i have already set up, i can show in green what slots are available and allow the user to select a green slot to book a new callout. The whole booking system is for Contractual ICT System Repair Services, so the user will be using the booking system to callout an engineer for a broken server or pc on their site.

Comment: @ADyson Will I have to create the background events serverside and send them with the events that are already booked in?

Comment: **Modifying Events**

_The editable property of a calendar determines whether the events on it can be modified. However, Background Events are not editable. They can not be dragged or resized._

That stumps me again :( Im going to have to add another event source and change the color of the events to a different color and then populate that from the server with free timeslots

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215232/discussion-between-cadsolutionsuk-and-adyson).